# Issues finding errors with code please? Cant figure whats wrong

Tags: java

```
Public class SalesSummary {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //declarations
    float month;
    float salesAmt ;
    final int SIZE = 12;
    String[] MONTH = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    float[] sales = new float[SIZE];
    char response;
    float total;
    float avrg;

    do{
      System.out.printIn ("Enter month");
      month = input.nextFloat();
      if (month > 1 || month < 12)
        System.out.printIn ("Invalid month");
      else 
        month = month - 1;
      System.out.printIn ("Enter sales amount");
      salesAmt = input.nextFloat();
      sales[month] = (sales[month] + salesAmt);
      System.out.printIn("Additional data (Y/N)?");
      response = input.next().charAt(0); 
      total = (sales[0] + sales[1] + sales[2] + sales[3] + sales[4] + sales[5] + sales[6] + sales[7] + sales[8] + sales[9] + sales[10] + sales[11]); 
      avrg = (total / SIZE);
    } while (response == 'y');

    for (int x = 0; x < MONTH.length; ++x) {
      System.out.println("Sales for " + MONTH[x] + " is: " + sales[x] + "Total is" + total + "Average is: " + avrg) ;
    }
  }
}
```

I was looking through the code and can't find why it isn't working. I believe it has something to do the with System.out.printIn() statements and the  sales[month] = (sales[month] + salesAmt)

Comment: This code won't even compile.  And is formatted so it's impossible to read.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much crazy talk.

Comment: What's wrong with that code? *Everything*.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Pretty new to coding.

Comment: In your code you're using `System.out.printIn` which is wrong. It should be `System.out.println`. Note the that lower case letter `L` not upper case letter `I`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code won't compile. Need to change the following for it to compile successfully at least:

- We are using a float (`month`) variable as an array index, which is not a valid syntax. Need to change type of month to `int`.
- After changing `month` to `int`, `input.nextFloat();` needs to be changed to `input.nextInt();`
- `System.out.printIn` needs to be changed to `System.out.println`

We can check it's behavior (and compare it with expected output) once it compiles and runs fine.